# WCF WebHTTP Binding throws 415 response

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wcf-binding, .net-4.6.1

I have a WCF web application, that does not work post-deployment and when I send request via postman it gives me an error "415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/xml' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'", and when I tried header with "application/soap+xml" then it throws 400 bad requests, please check my wcf web.config.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default" />
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyService.ServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="64" maxConcurrentSessions="400" maxConcurrentInstances="464" />
            </behavior>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="restFulBehaviour">
                 <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WsSecure" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttp" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" realm="" proxyCredentialType="None"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.ServiceBehavior" name="MyWCF.MyService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttp" name="MyService-endpoint" contract="MyWCF.IMyService" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" name="MyService-mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyService.ServiceBehavior" name="MyWCF.HealthCheck">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restFulBehaviour" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttp" name="health-endpoint" contract="MyWCF.IHealthCheck" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

**Code:**

```
 public interface IMyService
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "MyMethod",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        [OperationContract]
        Task<Response> MyMethod(Request request);
```

Comment: You need to add an http header to your request indicating the type is XML.  You do not have a soap because is it missing the Header and Body tags.  You just have plain xml.  Check the server documentation to see what is suppose to be in the http headers.

Comment: @jdweng That's an obvious thing that has been tried and not working.

Comment: Every Server is different.  Does server expect a SOAP?  A soap has an Envelope, Header (optional), and Body (optional).  See : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng Not able to get that.. I was looking solution on the posted problem

Comment: Error 415 indicates unsupported media type.  The server is looking at the http header Content Type.  So it looks like the server does not accept SOAP.  When you remove the SOAP header you get error 415,  There is something the server does not like with the xml you are sending.  Your xml has two root tags : system.serviceModel and system.webServer.  Well formed XML only has one root tag.  Most apps will only accept well formed xml.  Try sending only one root tag and see if the error 400 changes.

Comment: This is usually a client/server binding mismatch. You need to ensure that the client and server endpoints used are in sync in terms of binding and configuration.

Comment: @LanHuang I'm calling from the postman about which client/server, you are talking about, I have given the configuration in the question, can you please have a look and let me know what is incorrect.

Comment: I suggest that you remove the useless code, all your service endpoints use webHttpBinding instead of wsHttpBinding, but not all use behaviorConfiguration:restFulBehaviour.

Comment: I suggest that you [configure tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing) should be able to get more accurate information.